# faster way to find intersections?

Tags: regions, geometry, intersection

I'm writing a g-code generator for a CNC hot wire foam cutter. I have a block of foam (blue cuboid), and two airfoils that define the root and tip of a wing (shown as black curves on the ends of the foam block). These curves are just a list of `{x,y,z}` coordinates.

[image: machine setup]

The red spheres show the home positions for the stepper motors to which the wire is attached. The blue curves outside the foam block indicate the points the stepper motors need to go through to cut out the correct shape for the wing. To find these points, I've used `RegionIntersiction`, with `InfiniteLine` between points on the tip and root airfoils, and `InfinitePlane` representing the left or right (in the z-direction) positions of the stepper motors.

This is slow, so that when I map that function over all the points on the tip and root airfoils, it takes a couple of seconds to render. Is there a faster way to find the blue points?

Comment: `pt = {x1, y1, z1} (1 - t) + {x2, y2, z2} t;
pt3 = pt /. First@Solve[Last[pt] == z3, t];
pt4 = pt /. First@Solve[Last[pt] == z4, t];`? Given black points 1 and 2 and planes z == z3, z == z4, solve for blue points pt3, pt4; assuming the two sets of black points are paired to give a ruled surface for the wing. Assuming the given points are distinct, you should get general formulas for `pt3`, `pt4` into which you can plug the coordinates of each pair of black points so that you don't have to use `Solve` at each step.

Comment: If your black root foil points and black tip foil points are paired already, then you just need to scale each vector apprpriately. So, let's say one of the root foil points is `rootPoint1 = {x1,y1,z1}`, and one of the tip foil points is `tipPoint1 = {x2,y2,z2}`, and the z-position of the stepper at the tip is `z3`, then the following will get you the location for the stepper near the tip associated to those two points: `rootPoint1 + (tipPoint1 - rootPoint1) ((z3 - z1)/(z2 - z1))`. Do the similar thing for the stepper near the root. Create a function for that, and apply it to all pairs.

Comment: Gorgeous ME2. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I could have still done the ```RegionIntersection``` and ```InfiniteLine```/```InfinitePlane``` trick, if instead of putting in numbers, I just did it symbolically, it would have given me the same general expressions Michael's technique will develop.